# Why run certbot in a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a site working which has angular and node apps running in docker containers.  These are brought up in a docker-compose file which also mounts volumes linking to the letsencrypt certificates, and it all seems to work fine.  I created the letsencrypt certificates running certbot without a container.

I'm interested then, to understand why many people seem to run certbot in its own container in order to get and renew certificates?  That approach seems to add to the complexity by having another container ... what am I missing - is my approach 'wrong' for some reason?

Edit: I wanted to add some examples: [here](https://geko.cloud/nginx-and-ssl-with-certbot-in-docker-alpine/), [here](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71), [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose), and [here](https://www.humankode.com/ssl/how-to-set-up-free-ssl-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-using-docker-and-nginx) all run certbot in a container.  I would love to understand the benefits of containerising certbot.

Comment: I feel like this is a great question, but I'm not sure you'll get very many good answers.  Stackoverflow tries to keep opinion based answers off of the site.  One of the other stack exchange sites might be a better fit for this, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Thanks for responding....I undertand your point, although I would counter that I'm not after anyone's opinion on whether running certbot in a container is a good idea or not, but objective discussion of the benefits of doing so. But if SO isn't down with that ...

Answer (score 1):

Two advantages of running certbot in its own container are:

1. Management of certbot-generated files within the docker volumes subsystem: this allows you to keep these files isolated and to easily mount them into other containers without "polluting" your root filesystem.
2. Containing the possible effects of certbot to a limited set of files, rather than running it "unjailed" on your root fs.

I can't think of any particular disadvantages beyond some extra complexity (although if this is all managed within a single docker-compose file it's probably less complex than setting up your docker-based ecosystem and then separately configuring and running certbot).